# Composition of Relations, How to prove

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, function-and-relation-composition

I am facing difficulty in solving this, where I have to prove or find the counterexample for the below statement. Could anyone guide me on how do I go about solving this. Thanks in advance.

If R is a relation on a given set A such that RoRoR is a subset of R, then RoRoRoRoR is also a subset of R, where o denotes composition of the relations.

Comment: Have you tried looking for a small counterexample? Consider relations on sets with two or three elements, and see what you can find. If you fail to find a counterexample, then maybe that will point you toward a proof.

Comment: @Arthur : I am not able to find a counterexample. I tried many times. However, I am also not able to formalize a proof. Kindly help

Comment: You say you tried many times. What did you try?

Comment: I did it for set having 6 elements. But since we are having RoRoR as a subset of R, RoRoRoRoR automatically becomes a subset of R. I am able to deduce it after solving and intuitively also it sounds fine, however I am not able to establish a sound mathematical proof.

Comment: You added another $R$ to your problem statement. Are you certain that it is now correct?

Comment: Related deleted question by a different user: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3468820/if-r-is-a-relation-on-a-set-a-such-that-r3-subseteq-r-then-r5-subsete?noredirect=1#comment7131396_3468820

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that elements of $R^n$ are pairs $(a,c)$ with $a,c\in A$ such that there exist elements $b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots,b_{n-1}$ from $A$ such that $(a,b_1),(b_1,b_2),(b_2,b_3),\dots,(b_{n-2},b_{n-1}),(b_{n-1},c)$ are all elements of $R$.

Suppose that $R^3\subseteq R$.  That means in particular that if we have elements $a,b_1,b_2,c$ such that $(a,b_1),(b_1,b_2),(b_2,c)$ are all elements of $R$ then $(a,c)$ is also an element of $R$.

Now, suppose that $(a,e)\in R^5$.

That means in particular that there exist $b_1,b_2,c,d_4$ such that $(a,b_1),(b_1,b_2),(b_2,c),(c,d_4),(d_4,e)$ are all pairs in $R$.

Then we have

$\underbrace{\underbrace{(a,b_1)(b_1,b_2)(b_2,c)}_{(a,c)}(c,d_4)(d_4,e)}_{(a,e)}$

That is, since $(a,b_1)(b_1,b_2)(b_2,c)$ are all elements of $R$ we have $(a,c)\in R^3$ and since $R^3\subseteq R$ we have that $(a,c)$ is in $R$ and since $(a,c)(c,d_4)(d_4,e)$ are all elements of $R$ that $(a,e)$ is also in $R^3$ implying that $(a,e)$ is also in $R$ as well.

So, as a result, $(a,e)\in R^5$ implies that $(a,e)\in R$ implying $R^5\subseteq R$